# I can't understand that why is the output of this code 15, 4, 6

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

**I have written this piece of code, but the output of this code is not what i expected. Can anyone explain me how come 15, 4, 6 is the output.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int a = 1, b = 1, d = 1;
    printf("%d, %d, %d", ++a + ++a + a++, a++ + ++b, ++d + d++ + a++);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

Comment: @UnholySheep Yeah, I understood !!! Thanks